# Using return 0; in void function is possible or not?

Tags: c

I've recently submit a project of multiply and division of large numbers to my instructor using C programming in code::blocks.
in the middle of the code, mistakenly I used return 0; in a void function:

```
void division_function (char str1[MAX_STR_LEN], char str2[MAX_STR_LEN])
{
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);
    int num1[len1];
    int num2[len2];

    // In case the second number has more digits:
    if (len2 > len1)
    {
        printf("\nResult of division = 0");
        printf("\nRemainder = %s ", str1);
        return 0 ;
    }
    //rest of the code
```

anyway after submitting the instructor mailed me that the code failed due to using return a value in void function! 
I know I should have used (return;) instead of (return 0;) because void function return nothing!
my problem is why I don't get any errors in my console!
simply I tested this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void function ();
int main()
{
    function();
    return 0;
}
void function ()
{
    printf("OK");
    return 0;
}
```

again I got no error and the output is OK.
this time my problem is not getting the error which seems I should get!

Comment: It gives an error for me 'error: void function `function' should not return a value [-Wreturn-type]`. Perhaps your native compiler does not have copilation flag `return-type` enabled.

Comment: the close braclet in division_function is missing.

Comment: I know, I didn't put the rest of the code . it is too long!

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @ Jabberwocky : GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: Next time, please compile with **at least** `-Wall -Wextra`. Also, I'd advise against using codeblocks; use a text editor with syntax highlighting (gedit should be ok) and plain old Makefiles instead. They are way more flexible if written properly and you don't risk not seeing the compiler warnings because of a layout change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did get a warning, which you chose to ignore. Codeblocks default installation is a gcc/mingw one, which does give the following warning:

> warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void

If you compile with `-pedantic-errors`, it will turn into an error.

---

The recommended setting for beginners is to go Settings -> Compiler, check the following options:

- Enable all common compiler warnings (-Wall)
- Enable extra compiler warnings (-Wextra)
- Treat as errors the warnings demanded by strict ISO C (-pedantic-errors)

Preferably you should also add an option `-std=c11` which I don't think exists by default in Codeblocks.

Comment: @ Lundin: Thanks. I checked those three options and now I get the error.

Comment: additionally: I reinstalled Codeblocks. by default, these options are not checked. indeed nothing is checked in Settings -> Compiler.  surprisingly I had 2 other warning and error which didn't show me as well: 1) unused variable 2) an extra "\" in a text in printf function!

Comment: @peacekeeper You don't need to have these checked to get the warning I quoted. Having them checked is just good practice. And `pedantic-errors` turns warnings into errors while checking for standard compliance, so it is good too.

Answer (score 6):

In *standard* C, it's not possible to `return` anything with a `void` function - the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic.

Also if a function is non-`void`, then you *must* return something that's either the same type or implicitly convertible to the return type. The exception to this rule is `main`, where the compiler will insert an implicit `return 0;` if it's missing.

Note that in C, you should mark your function prototype as having `void` parameters:

```
void function (void);
```

which is an important difference between C and C++.

Unless you can configure the compiler so it fails compilation in such an instance, it is defective and you ought to consider switching it.

Comment: What vexes me is that `return;` in a non-void function is a constraint violation, but flowing of the end is "mere" undefined behavior.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I quite like it that way though as it's impossible to detect flowing to the end in full generality. Java tries to and gets it horribly wrong.

Comment: But it's C :( The flow of control is is devilishly simple compared to languages where every token can potentially throw an exception.

Comment: More likely they got a warning, but didn't compile as a separate step, just hit F9 (run) and the code compiled. gcc likes to build executables from non-conforming C unless you put it in place first.

Comment: @  Lundin: without checking The recommended settings you mentioned, hitting rebuild shows me errors but hitting run (f9) or build and run shows nothing.